# org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, runtime-error, resttemplate

I am getting the below error while running through linux script. This is not happening always sometimes it succeeded and sometimes the below error.:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal
>   Server Error
>           at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)
>           at com.gtech.lsp.utils.SynchronizeRetailerData.main(SynchronizeRetailerData.java:42)
>   Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal
>   Server Error
>           at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:486)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:443)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
>           at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:199)

I am initializing the `RestTemplate` as below:

```
url = PreferencesUtil.getInstance().getAppRoot()
                .get("lsp.sync.retailer.url", "http://localhost:8080/lsptx/public/syncRetailer");
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();          
        restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class, jurId);
```

could you please help me on this?

Comment: Did you check your log-file for the lsptx application? A HTTP 500 signals that the lsptx application is generating an error.

Comment: Yes, I checked it says:

GET request for "http://<ipaddress>:8080/lsptx/public/syncRetailer" resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler

Comment: hey hi..can you please tel how did you solve the problem? i am facing the same issue when trying to save json